# WinRT equivalent of these .Net culture methods?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, currentculture

What is the WinRT equivalent of these items from the .NET framework?

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID
Encoding.GetEncoding(int codePage)
Encoding.CodePage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK LCID was gone in Silverlight too, at least on Windows Phone and if you really needed it - you had to grab a table from the documentation like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx).

Same thing with encoding - you would need to map the names to code pages, e.g. with the table from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Text.Encoding%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true).

Comment: You can call the Win32 `LocaleNameToLCID` to convert a locale name to an LCID.  Globalization is _way_ outside my area of expertise (or even familiarity), so I have no idea what incantation would precisely correspond to the C# in the question.  But, many of the Win32 locale functions are callable from within a Windows Store app.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot there that in this world .NET and native code are pretty good friends.

Answer (score 1):

LCIDs and code pages are deprecated in WinRT.
You should migrate away from LCID to use language names. You should migrate away from using code page encodings to Unicode encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16).

Comment: I generally agree, but there are tons of complex solutions that rely on LCIDs where that sort of migration is simply not possible.

Comment: I would love to migrate away from RTF as well. RTF parsing is where I needed this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here the mapping of the [encodings supported by the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Text.Encoding%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true):

```
class CodePage
{
    public static string GetEncodingString(int codePage)
    {
        string encodingString = null;
        switch (codePage)
        {
            case 37:
                encodingString = "IBM037"; // IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada)
                break;
            case 437:
                encodingString = "IBM437"; // OEM United States
                break;
            case 500:
                encodingString = "IBM500"; // IBM EBCDIC (International)
                break;
            case 708:
                encodingString = "ASMO-708"; // Arabic (ASMO 708)
                break;
            case 720:
                encodingString = "DOS-720"; // Arabic (DOS)
                break;
            case 737:
                encodingString = "ibm737"; // Greek (DOS)
                break;
            case 775:
                encodingString = "ibm775"; // Baltic (DOS)
                break;
            case 850:
                encodingString = "ibm850"; // Western European (DOS)
                break;
            case 852:
                encodingString = "ibm852"; // Central European (DOS)
                break;
            case 855:
                encodingString = "IBM855"; // OEM Cyrillic
                break;
            case 857:
                encodingString = "ibm857"; // Turkish (DOS)
                break;
            case 858:
                encodingString = "IBM00858"; // OEM Multilingual Latin I
                break;
            case 860:
                encodingString = "IBM860"; // Portuguese (DOS)
                break;
            case 861:
                encodingString = "ibm861"; // Icelandic (DOS)
                break;
            case 862:
                encodingString = "DOS-862"; // Hebrew (DOS)
                break;
            case 863:
                encodingString = "IBM863"; // French Canadian (DOS)
                break;
            case 864:
                encodingString = "IBM864"; // Arabic (864)
                break;
            case 865:
                encodingString = "IBM865"; // Nordic (DOS)
                break;
            case 866:
                encodingString = "cp866"; // Cyrillic (DOS)
                break;
            case 869:
                encodingString = "ibm869"; // Greek, Modern (DOS)
                break;
            case 870:
                encodingString = "IBM870"; // IBM EBCDIC (Multilingual Latin-2)
                break;
            case 874:
                encodingString = "windows-874"; // Thai (Windows)
                break;
            case 875:
                encodingString = "cp875"; // IBM EBCDIC (Greek Modern)
                break;
            case 932:
                encodingString = "shift_jis"; // Japanese (Shift-JIS)
                break;
            case 936:
                encodingString = "gb2312"; // Chinese Simplified (GB2312) *
                break;
            case 949:
                encodingString = "ks_c_5601-1987"; // Korean
                break;
            case 950:
                encodingString = "big5"; // Chinese Traditional (Big5)
                break;
            case 1026:
                encodingString = "IBM1026"; // IBM EBCDIC (Turkish Latin-5)
                break;
            case 1047:
                encodingString = "IBM01047"; // IBM Latin-1
                break;
            case 1140:
                encodingString = "IBM01140"; // IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada-Euro)
                break;
            case 1141:
                encodingString = "IBM01141"; // IBM EBCDIC (Germany-Euro)
                break;
            case 1142:
                encodingString = "IBM01142"; // IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway-Euro)
                break;
            case 1143:
                encodingString = "IBM01143"; // IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden-Euro)
                break;
            case 1144:
                encodingString = "IBM01144"; // IBM EBCDIC (Italy-Euro)
                break;
            case 1145:
                encodingString = "IBM01145"; // IBM EBCDIC (Spain-Euro)
                break;
            case 1146:
                encodingString = "IBM01146"; // IBM EBCDIC (UK-Euro)
                break;
            case 1147:
                encodingString = "IBM01147"; // IBM EBCDIC (France-Euro)
                break;
            case 1148:
                encodingString = "IBM01148"; // IBM EBCDIC (International-Euro)
                break;
            case 1149:
                encodingString = "IBM01149"; // IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic-Euro)
                break;
            case 1200:
                encodingString = "utf-16"; // Unicode *
                break;
            case 1201:
                encodingString = "unicodeFFFE"; // Unicode (Big endian) *
                break;
            case 1250:
                encodingString = "windows-1250"; // Central European (Windows)
                break;
            case 1251:
                encodingString = "windows-1251"; // Cyrillic (Windows)
                break;
            case 1252:
                encodingString = "Windows-1252"; // Western European (Windows) *
                break;
            case 1253:
                encodingString = "windows-1253"; // Greek (Windows)
                break;
            case 1254:
                encodingString = "windows-1254"; // Turkish (Windows)
                break;
            case 1255:
                encodingString = "windows-1255"; // Hebrew (Windows)
                break;
            case 1256:
                encodingString = "windows-1256"; // Arabic (Windows)
                break;
            case 1257:
                encodingString = "windows-1257"; // Baltic (Windows)
                break;
            case 1258:
                encodingString = "windows-1258"; // Vietnamese (Windows)
                break;
            case 1361:
                encodingString = "Johab"; // Korean (Johab)
                break;
            case 10000:
                encodingString = "macintosh"; // Western European (Mac)
                break;
            case 10001:
                encodingString = "x-mac-japanese"; // Japanese (Mac)
                break;
            case 10002:
                encodingString = "x-mac-chinesetrad"; // Chinese Traditional (Mac)
                break;
            case 10003:
                encodingString = "x-mac-korean"; // Korean (Mac) *
                break;
            case 10004:
                encodingString = "x-mac-arabic"; // Arabic (Mac)
                break;
            case 10005:
                encodingString = "x-mac-hebrew"; // Hebrew (Mac)
                break;
            case 10006:
                encodingString = "x-mac-greek"; // Greek (Mac)
                break;
            case 10007:
                encodingString = "x-mac-cyrillic"; // Cyrillic (Mac)
                break;
            case 10008:
                encodingString = "x-mac-chinesesimp"; // Chinese Simplified (Mac) *
                break;
            case 10010:
                encodingString = "x-mac-romanian"; // Romanian (Mac)
                break;
            case 10017:
                encodingString = "x-mac-ukrainian"; // Ukrainian (Mac)
                break;
            case 10021:
                encodingString = "x-mac-thai"; // Thai (Mac)
                break;
            case 10029:
                encodingString = "x-mac-ce"; // Central European (Mac)
                break;
            case 10079:
                encodingString = "x-mac-icelandic"; // Icelandic (Mac)
                break;
            case 10081:
                encodingString = "x-mac-turkish"; // Turkish (Mac)
                break;
            case 10082:
                encodingString = "x-mac-croatian"; // Croatian (Mac)
                break;
            case 12000:
                encodingString = "utf-32"; // Unicode (UTF-32) *
                break;
            case 12001:
                encodingString = "utf-32BE"; // Unicode (UTF-32 Big endian) *
                break;
            case 20000:
                encodingString = "x-Chinese-CNS"; // Chinese Traditional (CNS)
                break;
            case 20001:
                encodingString = "x-cp20001"; // TCA Taiwan
                break;
            case 20002:
                encodingString = "x-Chinese-Eten"; // Chinese Traditional (Eten)
                break;
            case 20003:
                encodingString = "x-cp20003"; // IBM5550 Taiwan
                break;
            case 20004:
                encodingString = "x-cp20004"; // TeleText Taiwan
                break;
            case 20005:
                encodingString = "x-cp20005"; // Wang Taiwan
                break;
            case 20105:
                encodingString = "x-IA5"; // Western European (IA5)
                break;
            case 20106:
                encodingString = "x-IA5-German"; // German (IA5)
                break;
            case 20107:
                encodingString = "x-IA5-Swedish"; // Swedish (IA5)
                break;
            case 20108:
                encodingString = "x-IA5-Norwegian"; // Norwegian (IA5)
                break;
            case 20127:
                encodingString = "us-ascii"; // US-ASCII *
                break;
            case 20261:
                encodingString = "x-cp20261"; // T.61
                break;
            case 20269:
                encodingString = "x-cp20269"; // ISO-6937
                break;
            case 20273:
                encodingString = "IBM273"; // IBM EBCDIC (Germany)
                break;
            case 20277:
                encodingString = "IBM277"; // IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway)
                break;
            case 20278:
                encodingString = "IBM278"; // IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden)
                break;
            case 20280:
                encodingString = "IBM280"; // IBM EBCDIC (Italy)
                break;
            case 20284:
                encodingString = "IBM284"; // IBM EBCDIC (Spain)
                break;
            case 20285:
                encodingString = "IBM285"; // IBM EBCDIC (UK)
                break;
            case 20290:
                encodingString = "IBM290"; // IBM EBCDIC (Japanese katakana)
                break;
            case 20297:
                encodingString = "IBM297"; // IBM EBCDIC (France)
                break;
            case 20420:
                encodingString = "IBM420"; // IBM EBCDIC (Arabic)
                break;
            case 20423:
                encodingString = "IBM423"; // IBM EBCDIC (Greek)
                break;
            case 20424:
                encodingString = "IBM424"; // IBM EBCDIC (Hebrew)
                break;
            case 20833:
                encodingString = "x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended"; // IBM EBCDIC (Korean Extended)
                break;
            case 20838:
                encodingString = "IBM-Thai"; // IBM EBCDIC (Thai)
                break;
            case 20866:
                encodingString = "koi8-r"; // Cyrillic (KOI8-R)
                break;
            case 20871:
                encodingString = "IBM871"; // IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic)
                break;
            case 20880:
                encodingString = "IBM880"; // IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Russian)
                break;
            case 20905:
                encodingString = "IBM905"; // IBM EBCDIC (Turkish)
                break;
            case 20924:
                encodingString = "IBM00924"; // IBM Latin-1
                break;
            case 20932:
                encodingString = "EUC-JP"; // Japanese (JIS 0208-1990 and 0212-1990)
                break;
            case 20936:
                encodingString = "x-cp20936"; // Chinese Simplified (GB2312-80) *
                break;
            case 20949:
                encodingString = "x-cp20949"; // Korean Wansung *
                break;
            case 21025:
                encodingString = "cp1025"; // IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Serbian-Bulgarian)
                break;
            case 21866:
                encodingString = "koi8-u"; // Cyrillic (KOI8-U)
                break;
            case 28591:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-1"; // Western European (ISO) *
                break;
            case 28592:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-2"; // Central European (ISO)
                break;
            case 28593:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-3"; // Latin 3 (ISO)
                break;
            case 28594:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-4"; // Baltic (ISO)
                break;
            case 28595:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-5"; // Cyrillic (ISO)
                break;
            case 28596:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-6"; // Arabic (ISO)
                break;
            case 28597:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-7"; // Greek (ISO)
                break;
            case 28598:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-8"; // Hebrew (ISO-Visual) *
                break;
            case 28599:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-9"; // Turkish (ISO)
                break;
            case 28603:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-13"; // Estonian (ISO)
                break;
            case 28605:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-15"; // Latin 9 (ISO)
                break;
            case 29001:
                encodingString = "x-Europa"; // Europa
                break;
            case 38598:
                encodingString = "iso-8859-8-i"; // Hebrew (ISO-Logical) *
                break;
            case 50220:
                encodingString = "iso-2022-jp"; // Japanese (JIS) *
                break;
            case 50221:
                encodingString = "csISO2022JP"; // Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana) *
                break;
            case 50222:
                encodingString = "iso-2022-jp"; // Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana - SO/SI) *
                break;
            case 50225:
                encodingString = "iso-2022-kr"; // Korean (ISO) *
                break;
            case 50227:
                encodingString = "x-cp50227"; // Chinese Simplified (ISO-2022) *
                break;
            case 51932:
                encodingString = "euc-jp"; // Japanese (EUC) *
                break;
            case 51936:
                encodingString = "EUC-CN"; // Chinese Simplified (EUC) *
                break;
            case 51949:
                encodingString = "euc-kr"; // Korean (EUC) *
                break;
            case 52936:
                encodingString = "hz-gb-2312"; // Chinese Simplified (HZ) *
                break;
            case 54936:
                encodingString = "GB18030"; // Chinese Simplified (GB18030) *
                break;
            case 57002:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-de"; // ISCII Devanagari *
                break;
            case 57003:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-be"; // ISCII Bengali *
                break;
            case 57004:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-ta"; // ISCII Tamil *
                break;
            case 57005:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-te"; // ISCII Telugu *
                break;
            case 57006:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-as"; // ISCII Assamese *
                break;
            case 57007:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-or"; // ISCII Oriya *
                break;
            case 57008:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-ka"; // ISCII Kannada *
                break;
            case 57009:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-ma"; // ISCII Malayalam *
                break;
            case 57010:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-gu"; // ISCII Gujarati *
                break;
            case 57011:
                encodingString = "x-iscii-pa"; // ISCII Punjabi *
                break;
            case 65000:
                encodingString = "utf-7"; // Unicode (UTF-7) *
                break;
            case 65001:
                encodingString = "utf-8"; // Unicode (UTF-8) *
                break;
        }

        return encodingString;
    }
}
```